# Losing data in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

Struggling with this project - I have a multidimensional associative array that is being parsed to pull out tablenames, fieldnames and data for insertion into a mysql db.  In the array2query function, if the key:value is a top level pair, then the $tablename is set to 'project', otherwise $tablename=array name (discarding array[0] array names).  Data is NOT coming users, it's coming from API call in a json file.  Implementation will use PDO for writing to mysql db.

I'm getting a undeclared variable notice on $sql.  If I declare it inside the function, it gets reset to empty during the foreach loop and I lose part of the $sql string that has been built (all 'project' tablename data).

I also need to discard data where $element is null or empty but not 0 or 'false' which I can't seem to find a way to do cleanly.

How do I properly handle the NOTICE without losing the existing string?

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

//read the json file contents
$data = file_get_contents('c:\wamp64\www\json\test.json');
$data1 = preg_replace('/("\w+"):(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $data);
$array1 = json_decode($data1, true);

function array2query(array $array1, $tableName = ''){
       $sql="";  // not declaring variable results in NOTICE; declaring results in $sql being reset to "" during foreach loop
       foreach ($array1 as $key => $element) {
            if (is_array($element)) {
            // if key is integer then skip - it is the first level of array, keep the $tablename    
                $key = is_int($key) ? $tableName : $key;
                array2query($element, $key);
            } else {
                if ($tableName === '') {
                $tableName = 'project';
                }
            $sql .= 'INSERT INTO ' . $tableName . ' (' . rtrim($key, ',') . ') VALUES (' . rtrim($element, ',') . ');';
            //    }        
            } 
       }    
       echo $sql;  //dump to screen; missing non-nested values from tablename 'project' 
       return $sql;
    }

$array_query=array2query($array1);
```

Thank you for looking at this.  Test data is at http://pastebin.com/iSvqCMxb

EDIT:
Screen dump from echo:

```
INSERT INTO Contacts (ContactType) VALUES (Sales);
INSERT INTO Contacts (ContactAddressId) VALUES (ec4539c0-9012-4b4f-a590-bee11cc91109);
INSERT INTO Contacts (ExportId) VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Vendors (VendorId) VALUES (c3abfde4-4390-4e09-aa5f-60284613c8c5);
INSERT INTO Vendors (Name) VALUES (Fabrication Specialists);
INSERT INTO Vendors (ShortName) VALUES (Fabspec);
```

This is missing all "INSERT INTO (project)... " statements.

Comment: code you paste us what is dumped on the screen through `echo $sql;`? it doesn't have to be all the lines, just 4 or 5 to get an idea.

Comment: @Webeng - posted, let me know if you need to see more.

Comment: $sql doesn't get reset globally. Your function is recursive, so $sql is local to each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create your string by calling a function recursively, you must return the value through a parameter using a reference instead of the return statement.

Change your function signature:

```
function array2query(array $array1, &$sql, $tableName = '')
```

Then call the function with a variable that will collect your SQL statements:

```
$sql = '';
$array_query=array2query($array1, $sql);
```

Remember to change the recursive call too:

```
if (is_array($element)) {
    $key = is_int($key) ? $tableName : $key;
    array2query($element, $sql, $key);
}
```

Hope this helps, I cannot really test it now.

Comment: why can't the recursive function have a return statement? If I call the function inside itself, and it is returned inside itself, then wouldn't that 'export' the `$sql` value appropriately to the outer function and not loose any of its value?

Comment: No, the value of $sql is local to each iteration, it doesn't get passed to itself by default. That's the beauty (and the pain) of recursive functions  ; )

Comment: @MadDog - perfect solution!  I have another issue now that I'll post as a new question...

Answer (score 0):

```
array2query($element, $key);
```

replace with

```
$sql .= array2query($element, $key);
```

Comment: This should resolbe the 'missing non-nested values from tablename 'project' ' issue. You shouldn;t have the notice when defining $sql as you do in the code above.

Comment: I don't see how setting $sql (which is 'INSERT INTO ' . $tableName . ' (' . rtrim($key, ',') . ') VALUES (' . rtrim($element, ',') . ');'."<br>";) to $sql .= array2query($element, $key); works.  Looks like the entire query would be lost.

Comment: Only quickly - @MadDog's response was perfect and I understood it better.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

from the information dumped from your echo, it seems that there is information missing in the array generated (inferred from the echoed line of code: `INSERT INTO Contacts (ExportId) VALUES ();`).

Also I believe you are missing apostrophes around string values being inserted into your sql statement, for instance, this line of code:

```
INSERT INTO Vendors (ShortName) VALUES (Fabspec);
```

should be this line of code:

```
INSERT INTO Vendors (ShortName) VALUES ('Fabspec');
```

**PROPOSED SOLUTION:**

Since I do not have the power to change the format of the information in the file `'c:\wamp64\www\json\test.json'`, I can only make a workaround so that the code works in cases when there is no data available in an element of the array.

First I would solve the apostophe issue by replacing this line of code:

```
$sql .= 'INSERT INTO ' . $tableName . ' (' . rtrim($key, ',') . ') VALUES (' . rtrim($element, ',') . ');';
```

with this code:

```
$column = rtrim($key, ',');
$value_inserted = rtrim($element, ',');
$ap = ""
switch ($column)
{
    case ('Name')
        $ap = "'";
    break;
    case ('ShortName')
        $ap = "'";
    break;
    //create a case for all the situations where 
    //the specific column stores string values

    default:
    {
        if ($value_inserted == "")
        {
           $value_inserted = 0;
        }
    }
}

$sql .= 'INSERT INTO ' . $tableName . ' ($column) VALUES ('$ap.$value_inserted.$ap');';
```

What the previous code will do is insert an apostrophe on both ends of your inserted value inside the sql statement when the column in question requires a string.

The default part of the switch statement is only executed when a string is not the datatype of the column in question, so I took the chance to use this portion of the code to verify if the value inside the `$inserted_value` was empty (which should be what is causing your error). In those cases, I placed a Zero, however you can place whichever value you link.

Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: True for the apostrophes, the resulting queries would fail, but the problem is not there. Recursion doesn't get the previous $sql iteration, as pointed out by @Mad Dog.

Comment: @Webomatik Thanks for the feedback, though I have to say I disagree with you. `NOTICE` error seemed to be the problem he was focusing on. From the echoed values, it's noticeable he has values missing just like his notice suggests, which can be solved by altering the input going into the `$sql` statement. Correct me if I am wrong but that seems to be what is causing the `NOTICE`. There might be a problem with the recursiveness of the function which I could have overlooked, though I tried to focus on what he was specifically asking.

Comment: you are so right about about the problem raised by Scubadiver, but unfortunately, there also is a serious recursion problem... so everyone is right . Or wrong  ; )

Comment: @Webomatik hahah yeah I guess so.

Comment: Everyone was right but me!  Thanks for the help.  I am unable to get the switch statement to work however - getting a syntax error.  I'm focusing on getting the data set correct right now - I'll get to the insert statement later today I hope.

Comment: @Scubadiver no problem dude. If you have any other doubts, create another question and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

@Mad Dog is right, there lies your problem (at least the recursion one).

This block of code works fine, using a small part of your data array:

```
$sql="";
function array2query(array $array1, $tableName = '', &$sql){
   //$sql="";  // not declaring variable results in NOTICE; declaring results in $sql being reset to "" during foreach loop
   foreach ($array1 as $key => $element) {
        if (is_array($element)) {
        // if key is integer then skip - it is the first level of array, keep the $tablename    
            $key = is_int($key) ? $tableName : $key;
            array2query($element, $key, $sql);
        } else {
            if ($tableName === '') {
            $tableName = 'project';
            }
        $sql .= 'INSERT INTO ' . $tableName . ' (' . rtrim($key, ',') . ') VALUES (' . rtrim($element, ',') . ');' . "\r\n";
        } 
   }    
   //echo $sql;  //dump to screen; missing non-nested values from tablename 'project' 
   return $sql;
}
$rez = $array_query=array2query($array1, '', $sql);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($rez);
echo '</pre>';
```

THEN, you also need to quote your SQL values, as already pointed out by @Webeng.